# Postgresql Access Control

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a Postgresql database with a new owner for which I did the following:

```
postgres=# create user saurabhd;

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE test_db OWNER saurabhd;

postgres=# ALTER USER saurabhd PASSWORD 'spassword'
```

Evidently, the new user and Database were created from postgres user(default user). \l command showed the following:

```
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 test_db   | saurabhd | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 |
```

As can be seen, the owner name for database test_db is saurabhd. Although, I can still access the DB test_db with 'postgres' user and modify the DB.

Is there a way, I can restrict postgres user(and all other users except saurabhd) from accessing the DB test_db?

Answer (score 0):

ALTER ROLE

The management of roles in PostgreSQL allows different configurations, among them are:

- SUPERUSER / NOSUPERUSER. Super User, privileges to create databases
  and users.
- CREATEDB / NOCREATEDB. Create databases.
- CREATEROLE / NOCREATEROLE. Create roles.
- CREATEUSER / NOCREATEUSER. Create users.
- LOGIN / NOLOGIN. This attribute makes the difference between a role
  and a user. Since the user has permissions to access the database
  through a client.
- PASSWORD. Allows you to change the password.
- VALID UNTIL. Expiration of users.

To change the configuration of a user or role we must execute the following command.

```
ALTE ROLE <nombre del rol> WITH <opciones>
```

Create a database with a specific user as owner
All databases that we create with a user that has the CREATEDB privileges automatically assign the user as the owner. If what we want to create is a limited user, the way to create it with a specific database will be:

```
CREATE DATABASE user OWNER saurabhd ;
```

Assigning super user permissions to a user
The super user license is the highest. With this user you can manage all the objects of the database engine.

To assign this privilege to a role we do it with the following command:

```
ALTER ROLE saurabhd WITH SUPERUSER;
```

Assign all permissions to a user to an existing database
When we have just created a user and want to give permissions to an existing database, we can use the following command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE nameBase TO saurabhd;
```